# Can we automatically create a XML database during compilation with Inno Setup?

Tags: xml, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a very simple support installer that updates several XML databases with new versions:

```
[Files]
Source: "MSA_PublicTalks_???.xml"; DestDir: "{param:InstallPath}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Each of the database files has a `Version` attribute. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitles Version="1.0">
    <!-- English -->
    <eng>
        <PublicTalk Number="1" IssueDate="2015-09-01" Media="false">Theme</PublicTalk>
        <PublicTalk Number="1" IssueDate="2015-09-01" Media="false">Theme</PublicTalk>
    </eng>
</PublicTalkTitles>
```

Each database file name includes the language code. For example:

```
MSA_PublicTalks_ENG.xml
```

Now, I have another database file, which is not part of the installer, that I want o put on my website. It looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitleUpdates>
    <Database Language="eng" Version="1.0"/>
    <Database Language="esp" Version="1.0"/>
</PublicTalkTitleUpdates>
```

What I would like to do is automate the creation of this latter database when I build this update installer:

1. Create new XML database
2. For each talk titles database ...
3. Extract the language code from the file name.
4. Locate the version number `n.n`.
5. Add an entry to the new database.
6. Save the new xml after compiling has finished.

Can we do this with Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$folder = 'c:\temp'
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$pattern = 'MSA_PublicTalks_(?<lang>[^.]+).xml'

$template = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitles Version="1.0">
</PublicTalkTitles>
"@

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($template)
$talkTitles = $doc.Root

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match $pattern }
foreach($file in $files)
{
   $file -Match $pattern | out-null
   $lang = $Matches['lang'].ToLower()

   $doc2 = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($file.fullname)
   $root = $doc2.Root
   $ver = $root.Attribute('Version').Value
   
   $database = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Database'))
   $language = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Language'),$lang)
   $database.Add($language)
   $version = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Version'),$ver)
   $database.Add($version)
   $talkTitles.Add($database)
}
$doc.Save($filename)
```

Comment: A new xml file will always be created with name of variable $filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'  If the script is working it will look like nothing happens.  Only when an error occurs will you see any output. Get-ChildItem only searches main folder.  If you are -Recurse it will search all subfolders.

Comment: You would either get an exception or you would get an output file.  I tested the code and it works.  Maybe the folder doesn't exist or the drive d:\ isn't being recognized.  An admin would have permission to write so I do not think it is an access issue.  Try running script by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: No.  You would be getting errors is there was a setup issue.  You should get a test.xml file with no databases if the files were not found.  But you should always get the test.xml when there are no errors.  Run a very simple PS script like : Write-Host 'Hello World'  You can add Write-Host messages inside PS script to help debug.

Comment: Put the hello world script in the folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and see if it runs.  This is where the ps source is located.  PS uses the environmental variable PSModulePath.  I want to see if PS is installed properly or the PSModulePath is wrong.

Comment: I run PS using a shortcut.   I go to Start and type Powershell.  Then Pin to Taskbar.

Comment: I don't know a lot about execution policy especially with d:\.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.4#example-7-unblock-a-script-to-run-it-without-changing-the-execution-policy

Comment: Run from your c drive.  Add to beginning of script : c:\.  You will switch to c drive.  Code will still work if you include in the PATHs the d:.

Comment: Lets tidy up the comments here. If I run `powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\update.ps1` from a administrator command line console it works.  So I should be able to interface this into my Inno Setup script.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this.  A child script usually executes under the properties of the parent script.  If you create a top level script that sets execution policy, and then calls the Inno Script the Admin should be passed from the top level down through the child scripts.

Comment: I have it compiling in Inno Setup. Thanks. The only thing is that my folder that has all the XML files has one other file in there `MSA_PublicTalks_Info.xml` and we need to ignore that file. It is being picked up. All the files of interest are `MSA_PublicTalks_???.xml`.

Comment: Got it: `$pattern = 'MSA_PublicTalks_(?<lang>.{3}).xml'`.